# Fingerprint Verificaiton Android

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to record customer data including fingerprint via android tablet in banking project. When customer deposit or withdrawal money, will verify which customer by finger print data. Android device record fingerprint data and sync with webserver (asp.net). So, What is the best way to develop for fingerprint verification? If fingerprint device connect with android tablet is more easy, please suggest me.

Comment: how to sync with bankend(asp.net) and how to save fingerprint in db or save the path ...after user touch to verify how send it to server to match ..could you please provide more info,advice and guide because ihave the same scenario  from your project back ground ..thanks @thinzar

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `FingerprintManager` whic was added in API 23 (Android 6). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html

Also there is a demo project located here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

Answer (score 1):

Please start by reading this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template. For instance Samsung or iPhone only provide SDK to verify 1 user (user of device) but others manufacturers provide a SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

If you want to match user on server (fingerprint data of users are stored on server) you have to use an AFIS solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification.

Here some providers of AFIS solution:

- http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html
- http://au.nec.com/en_AU/solutions/security-and-public-safety/biometrics/afis-fingerprint-identification-features.html
- http://www.innovatrics.com/products
- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/afis/
- http://www.m2sys.com/automated-fingerprint-identification-system-afis/

Comment: @thinzar is it useful ?

Comment: so the scenario will be ..user tab device(phone support fingerprint if not use the attached device) to enter fingerprint as an image .....if i need to match fingerprint entered from phone to match it with the fingerprint in server i use AFIS...am i understand correctly?? ...my question how to save the fingerprint in my database i mean after user scan how to save it to database......is the matching need Encryption @LaurentY

Comment: No you cannot extract fingerprint image from integrated Fingerprint scanner (except on specific devices), you need external fingerprint scanner with associated SDK.
If you have large fingerprints to match you could do it on server with AFIS solution. If you want to match only few fingerprints some SDK allow you to do it on device.
You could save in picture or template (list of minutiaes) in db, depends on what your AFIS support formats. It's better if you encrypt data (picture or template) as you encrypt password of users.

Comment: the fingerprint from android 6.0 and up is the attach device going to solve this problem ??@LaurentY  thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot extract fingerprint template or image from integrated fingerprint scanner with Android SDK (6.0 and up), as I already said in my previous comment

Comment: the external fingerprint scanner with associated SDK. will scan the fingerprint below android SDK 6.0 @LaurentY

Comment: Yes with external fingerprint scanner and assosiated SDK you can get image or extract template of fingerprint, on version below 6.0 depending on SDK support

Comment: i may ask from time to time thanks in advance @LaurentY